# How does a Laravel controller method handle multiple Form Request parameters?

Tags: laravel

I am getting back to Laravel after several years and trying to understand how an already existing REST API coded in Laravel works. I can't understand how a particular controller method with multiple Form Request parameters works (or if it actually does).

The REST API was coded in Laravel 5.1. I've looked at the official documentation (both 5.1 and the latest) and tried to search the web and SO for related topics (e.g., "laravel controller multiple form requests", "laravel controller multiple type-hint requests", etc.), but I can't seem to find a clear explanation. Maybe I'm looking at it from a wrong angle.

```php
public function store(ProductRequest $productRequest, PromoRequest $promoRequest)
{
    // Validate product
    $product = new Product($productRequest->all());
    // Validate promo
    if ($promoRequest->get('promo')) {
        $promo = new Promo($promoRequest->get('promo'));
    }

    ...
}
```

In most documentation, the controller would accept only one Request object. I did actually see some examples that have multiple Form Request parameters, but often they were recommended to use only one Form Request. But best practice aside, how does this code work? When this method is called, how does Laravel know how to split the Request into two separate Form Request classes?

Please feel free to let me know if and how I can explain my question more clearly.

Comment: You stuff values such as instances, class definition (lazy load), or etc into container. Then give what needed, technically using Reflection to read controller class method parameters for above case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Laravel service container is a powerful tool for managing class
>   dependencies and performing dependency injection. Dependency injection
>   is a fancy phrase that essentially means this: class dependencies are
>   "injected" into the class via the constructor or, in some cases,
>   "setter" methods.

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container

Edit: **Additional question:** *Still, I can't understand how the HTTP request (which is only one) can be split into two different Request classes?*

The HTTP request isn't split; it is merely sent through both classes.

Ex:

```
function example(Request $request) { 
    $productRequest = new ProductRequest($request);
    $promoRequest = new PromoRequest($request);
}
```

Would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've scanned it and can understand better how the dependency injection works. Still, I can't understand how the HTTP request (which is only one) can be split into 2 different Request classes? Does that question make sense?

Comment: ah I see... Well, that really cleared things up a lot! Is this mentioned in any documentation at all? Anyway, thank you! This is definitely the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This produces error such as `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::__construct() must be of the type array, object given,`

Comment: @Shulz The above is pseudo-code meant to illustrate how it works and is not meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this:

```
function example(Request $request) { 
    $productRequest = new ProductRequest($request->all());
    $promoRequest = new PromoRequest($request->all());
}
```

but on validate you should change the way to this:

```
$data = $productRequest->validate($productRequest->rules());
```

another way that i test in laravel 8 is to add both form request object in methd parameters like :

```
function example(ProductRequest $productRequest,PromoRequest $promoRequest) { 
    $productRequest->validated();
    $promoRequest->validated();
}
```